# Caculating tail of a distribution

Tags: python, distribution, normal-distribution

I have data which follows approximately a normal distribution but with a heavy right tail as shown in the picture below. I have made the plot with seaborn `distplot` using a gaussian kernel density estimate (`hist=True, kde=True, norm_hist=True`).

Now I would like to calculate the point where the tail starts. In the picture I have marked this approximately with the red line.

How can I calculate the start point of the tail?

[image]

Comment: You could calculate the mean and standard deviation of your distribution, hoping their values are nearly the mu and sigma of the "gaussian part" of your distribution. Then you could add 3 or 4 sigma to mu to get the starting point of your tail.

Comment: Have you considered that it's unlikely to be normal?  Given no negative values and a very long upper tail, it could be Gamma or Weibull, or Beta if the upper end is also bounded.

Comment: @pjs Yes you are right, it is not normal distributed. It is perhaps more exponential distributed. How can I find the index of the tail for such a distribution?

Comment: @machinery It's not exponential either, or else zero would be the mode.  I don't think asking about the index of the tail is a meaningful question, unless you think you have a mixture of distributions, and even then it's ambiguous unless both distributions have bounded support.